# What would the units and zero divisors be?

Tags: abstract-algebra

in F3[x] for x^2-1
is x a unit or zero divisor?

I was wondering what the units and zero divisors would be
would they be 0,1,2,x+1,x-1,2x+2,2x-2
and then units x-2,x+2
HELP

Comment: Do you know the definition of a unit/zero-divisor?

Comment: i do but i'm really confused on how to go about this problem

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^2-1)$?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^2-1)$? If so, then here is how I would proceed.

***Exercise 1***: Prove the following sequence of isomorphisms:

$\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2-1)$

$\cong \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x+1)\times \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x-1)$

$\cong \mathbb{F}_3\times \mathbb{F}_3$.

***Exercise 2***: If $E$ and $F$ are fields, then compute the units and zero divisors in the product (as rings) $E\times F$.

***Exercise 3***: Compute the units and zero divisors in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2-1)$. (*Hint*: First, use your solution to ***Exercise 2***. Subsequently, backtrack via the isomorphisms in ***Exercise 1*** (units and zero divisors are preserved under isomorphisms).)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's neither.  If $F$ is a field, then consider any two polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$.  It is a fact that $deg(f(x) \cdot g(x)) = deg(f(x)) + deg(g(x))$.  Prove this!

So with this fact in mind, can you multiply any polynomial by $x^2 - 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ to get $1$ (the multiplicative identity)?  To get $0$?